# Java: how do I point at an array item through a variable?

Tags: java, arrays, variables

How do I point at an array item through a variable? Example:

```
String[] names;

int test = 10;

String myName = names[test];
```

The purpose is to get the same number item from 2 different arrays, for a username/password program.

Comment: It's very unclear what you mean. Can you provide more details?

Comment: how can you point for all item with a single variable?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: I mean, in the brackets, to specify an item within an array, how can I replace the number with a variable such as names[test] instead of names[10]

Comment: @101Cypher010 `names[test]` will work fine (assuming your array is properly initialized - which it isn't in your snippet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example:

```
String[] names;
int test = 10;
String myName = names[test];
```

The variable `myName` is a reference to the String in the array, but giving it new value:

```
myName = "fred";
```

will do nothing to the array - all you'd be doing is assigning a new reference to that variable.

To give the array element a bew value, do this:

```
names[test] = "fred";
```